# bash stuck at 3.2-24.el5 (Redhat)

Tags: bash, redhat, yum

I'm trying to update bash on our Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.6 server.
But it won't find an update later than "3.2-24.el5".
I've check and it is vulnerable for the shellshock vulnerability.
I've done yum clean-all, yum update bash, yum reinstall bash.
But it always comes back to just version "3.2-24.el5".

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a valid Red Hat subscription?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have a subscription anymore and that's not likely to change, and you don't care about **losing Redhat's (or other vendor's for that matter) support for this box** in the future, you can switch it to CentOS and have your box updated with its packages. It's not ideal, but it may still preferable to having a box you can't update anymore.

**You have been warned.**

> "All that you should need to do is install centos-release, remove
>   redhat-release rpms and just yum update the machine, which should
>   bring in all packages changed by CentOS ( since they will have a
>   slightly higher E-V-R )." - per KaranbirSingh on centos-list
>
> You may also wish to remove the "rhnplugin" from yum (not necessary but gives an error msg)
>
> OR - per Craig White on centos-list Mon, 29 Oct 2007 (updated for
>   5.8)...
>
> ```
> # cp /etc/redhat-release /etc/redhat-release-saved
> # rpm -e --nodeps redhat-release-notes redhat-release yum-rhn-plugin redhat-logos
> # rpm -ivh \ http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/i386/CentOS/centos-release-5-8.el5.centos.i386.rpm \
> http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/i386/CentOS/centos-release-notes-5.8-0.i386.rpm \
> http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/i386/CentOS/redhat-logos-4.9.99-11.el5.centos.noarch.rpm
> # yum update
> ```

Source:
http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/MigrationGuide

Link to the fixed package announcement in CentOS:
https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=48677

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't got a valid subscription you can [roll your own](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/158193/24379) bash package:

- Install [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm)
- Download the source file (http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-3.2.tar.gz)
- Download all patches (http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-3.2-patches/)
- `tar xzvf bash-3.2.tar.gz`
- Apply all patches, up to the latest `patch -p0 <bash32-054`
- `./configure --prefix=/usr`
- `make`
- `mkdir -p /tmp/bash`
- `make install DESTDIR=/tmp/bash`
- `mkdir -p /tmp/bash/bin`
- `mv /tmp/bash/usr/bin/bash /tmp/bash/bin/bash`
- `rm /tmp/bash/usr/share/info/dir`
- `ln -s /bin/bash /tmp/bash/bin/sh`
- `fpm -s dir -t rpm --epoch 1 -n bash -v 3.2.54 -p bash-3.2.54-1.rpm -C /tmp/bash .`
- `yum install bash-3.2.54-1.rpm`

Comment: Or just download the CentOS version...